# Yaks on Camel K does not find the integration .groovy file

Tags: apache-camel, citrus-framework, apache-camel-k

I'm using camel k on a project and I've tried use yaks framework for testing integrations routes.

When I execute the command to begin the test which is written in a .feature file the .groovy file is not found.
Does anyone have a clue about it?

**helloworld.feature**

```
Feature: Hello
    Scenario: Print hello message
        Given load Camel K integration myIntegration.groovy
        Given Camel K integration myIntegration is running
        Then Camel K integration myIntegration should print Hello world from Camel K!
```

**integration myIntegration.groovy**

```
from('timer:tick?period=10000')
  .setBody()
  .constant('Hello world from Camel K!')
  .to('log:info')
```

**CLI command**

```
yaks test helloworld.feature -n dev-camelk
```

**Logs:**

```
[test-helloworld-c91h513v71u96jkmfqbg-g56mw test-1] 1 Scenarios (1 failed)
[test-helloworld-c91h513v71u96jkmfqbg-g56mw test-1] 3 Steps (1 failed, 2 skipped)
[test-helloworld-c91h513v71u96jkmfqbg-g56mw test-1] 0m1.987s
**[test-helloworld-c91h513v71u96jkmfqbg-g56mw test-1] com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Failed to load Camel K integration from resource mob2.groovy**
[test-helloworld-c91h513v71u96jkmfqbg-g56mw test-1]     at org.citrusframework.yaks.camelk.CamelKSteps.loadIntegrationFromFile(CamelKSteps.java:141)
[test-helloworld-c91h513v71u96jkmfqbg-g56mw test-1]     at ✽.load Camel K integration mob2.groovy(classpath:org/citrusframework/yaks/helloworld.feature:3)
[test-helloworld-c91h513v71u96jkmfqbg-g56mw test-1] Caused by: **java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [myIntegration.groovy] cannot be opened because it does not exist**
[test-helloworld-c91h513v71u96jkmfqbg-g56mw test-1]     at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in the way you call it. The integration name is generally kebab case for Camel K integration, so, your feature must be:

```
Feature: Hello
Scenario: Print hello message
    Given load Camel K integration myIntegration.groovy
    Given Camel K integration my-integration is running
    Then Camel K integration my-integration should print Hello world from Camel K!
```

Then, you must provide the integration file resource via `--resource` option, such as:

```
yaks run helloworld.feature --resource myIntegration.groovy
```

Hope it helps!